# Can I use the gcal Google Calendar integration with Resources in FullCalendar Scheduler?

Tags: fullcalendar, google-calendar-api, scheduler

I'm attempting to integrate a Google Calendar for each resource in FullCalendar Scheduler (http://fullcalendar.io/scheduler/)

I currently have:

```
        googleCalendarApiKey: 'MYAPIKEY',
        resourceGroupField: 'level',
        resources: [
            { id: 'a', level: 'Level A', title: 'Room 3' },
            { id: 'b', level: 'Level B', title: 'Room 2' }
        ],
        eventSources: [
        { id: '1', googleCalendarId: 'blahblah2@group.calendar.google.com', resourceId: 'a' },
        { id: '2', googleCalendarId: 'blahblah2@group.calendar.google.com', resourceId: 'b' }
    ]
    });
```

Which is really just a guess....

Scheduler renders correctly however the events do not populate. The ordinary FullCalendar view with a single googlecalendarid works fine.

But the idea is I would then have a Google Calendar feeding events into each resource in the Scheduler agenda views.. Any suggestions? I can't find explicit documentation for this so perhaps it has not been implemented. Would appreciate work arounds however!

Comment: You want events from Google Calendar to be Scheduler Resources in FullCalendar? Did I understand that correctly? Why not parse the the [Events](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events#resource-representations) and try to make them into Scheduler Resources with the available data? This can be done on both sides of the spectrum

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here: https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/3020

Seems it has not been merged yet however can confirm adding

```
resourceId: sourceOptions.resourceId
```

To line 153 of gcal.js makes this work a treat :D